# Expose taxonomy term contextual filter in Layout Builder

Tags: views, layout-builder

I have created a view block for a content type of card. The card content type also has a taxonomy vocabulary where users can add new terms to that taxonomy vocabulary.
I have a contextual filter on this view block which filters by taxonomy ID. And this works in the views preview pane, e.g. I enter `1` and cards with the taxonomy term ID 1 are rendered in the preview.

[image: Screenshot of Views interface]

[image: Screenshot of contextual filter]

However, when I use Layout Builder and select the view block, I do not get an option to input what taxonomy term ID I want to use for the block. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Layout Builder block selection]

Comment: If you configured the contextual filter in view block once, then why this contextual filter needs to configured in block , I believe it should work w.r.t contextual filter configured in the view block, what issue you are facing here

Comment: I'm fairly sure my understanding of how to use contextual filters are flawed, but this is the use-case. I have a content type called card, and it includes a taxonomy term field. I would like to create a view block that shows only cards that have specific taxonomy terms. I thought using contextual filters, I could choose which term is being used, then place that block on a page with layout builder.

Comment: There are two different types of filter in views : filter criteria & contextual filter, you can follow this documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-contextual-filter-to-a-view to understand more about contextual filter

Comment: +1 I agree @huijing - there should be a field in the configuration in layout builder to add the contextual filter value(s). Simple as that.

Comment: @huijing take comfort in that others have this same issue and are also trying to find solutions with possibly some success, as do I. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3255977   One definitely should be able to pass parameters,i.e. contexual filters, to a block which is a Views display. Otherwise their usefulness (and of layout builder itself is very limited). Specifically look at this solution in that above issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3255977#comment-15018513

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_builder/ecosystem and here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/layout-builder/additional-modules to see if there might be an existing add-on extension module to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Pass value in contextual filter programmatically : using hook_views_pre_view(): (can add either .theme/.module file)

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

function Mythemename/Mymodulename_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {

  if ($view->id() == 'view_machine_name' && $display_id == 'view_display_machine_name') {
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
        // get taxonmoy field value from current node page
        $tid = $node->get('field_taxonomy')->target_id;
        if(!empty($tid)){
          $args[0] = $tid;
        }
      }  
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, this seems closer to what i want to achieve. but i'm a little confused about which ID is the filter criteria. let's say my page is node/16, but i want the cards of taxonomy term ID 2 to be displayed, how would the dynamic value from URL work here?

Comment: I have added steps 1-3 in ans how can use fixed value in contextual filter

Comment: does this mean that i will have to define new blocks every time i have a new taxonomy term? i think this ties back to my original question of whether it would be possible to pass a value from layout builder to the contextual filter in the block. seems like that is not possible?

Comment: Let say  /node/1 , in it's taxonomy field  has value 2, then you want to taxonomy id = 2 in contextual filter, similarly if editor update taxonomy id = 3 in /node/1 , for this particular scenario you want to contextual filter and pass taxonomy value i.e in the node, confirm Is this what you want?

Comment: yes. so to rephrase, i would like to reuse the same views block on different pages, but with the option to select what the taxonomy ID should be on different pages.

Comment: Yes this can be achieved using same view block in which needs to pass contextual filter value by customisation using hook_views_pre_view() ,added this code in ans for reference purpose

Comment: do i add this to the MYTHEME.theme file? this is not specific to layout builder though, right?

Comment: You can add either .theme or .module file, not specific to layout builder, this customisation work even if you place block directly without using layout builder